# Sublime Text 2 - SFTP plugin - keybinding shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

I've installed Sublime Text 2, and wbond's SFTP plugin.  This plugin installs a bunch of key shortcut bindings (and I can find the file in my preferences.. they're all there) but my shortcuts are not working.

In particular, I'm dying without the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> bindings.

How can I get these to work?!  I've never had this kind of trouble with sublime before.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+r","ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "sftp_browse_server"}, 
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+r","ctrl+alt+n"], "command":"sftp_last_server" },
```

Sublime Text 2 on Ubuntu 
3.2.0-49-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 18 17:39:32 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/usage#Usage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue on Windows 7 , shortcuts didn't work.
The solution in my case at least was : Preferences > Key Bindings Default >
and I changed the line
 `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+r","ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "sftp_browse_server"}` 
 to >`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "sftp_browse_server"}`

I think if it has two key combination it wants both of them to pressed to work.
I mean to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and release and then press again <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.
Silly, I know. So set one combination of keys you prefer.
I went with <kbd>b</kbd> personally. Hope this helps.